# How to pass variable and break loop in subprocess.Popen in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

**Main Script:**

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

video_names= ["Video1", "Video2", . . .]

#Initiate screen recording
for each video_name in video_names:
   proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ScreenRecorder.py', video_name], stdin=PIPE, shell=False)

#DO STUFF THAT I WANT TO RECORD

#BREAK LOOP IN SUBPROCESS
```

**ScreenRecorder.py:**

```
# importing the required packages
import cv2
import time
import sys


video_name = sys.argv[2]

recording_duration = 15

end_time = time.time() + recording_duration

while time.time() < end_time:
    
    # RECORD VIDEO
     
    # Stop recording when we press 'q'
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
 
# OUTPUT VIDEO
```

*I am running Python in VSCode on Windows*

I have a script which uses Popen to call [ScreenRecorder.py](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-screen-recorder-using-python/) as a subprocess which will need to run in parallel to the main script as it uses an infinite while loop to continuously capture frames.

The first issue is that I'm not sure how to pass variable `video_name` through such that a new video with a new title is created each time. The current `sys.argv[2]` doesn't work.

My second issue is that ScreenRecorder.py has an infinite while loop which I have temporarily changed to only record for 15 seconds. However the original code is set up to break the loop when the Q key is pressed. How can I set it up so that I can send the break condition from the parent code? - I don't mind how the loop is broken, it doesn't have to be a key press. I can't use proc.terminate() as the code after the loop in ScreenRecorder.py needs to run to output the video file.

To pass the variable I've tried to use both

```
video_name = sys.argv[1]
```

and

```
#In main script:
video_name = "videoname1"
proc.stdin.write(str(video_name).encode('UTF-8'))
proc.stdin.close()
```

but can't seem to get anywhere. I think the issue is I can't seem to work out how to use `stdin` properly.

Comment: `video_name = sys.argv[1]` seems to be correct. What didn't work?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(...)` doesn't actually *run* the process. Simply use `subprocess.run(...)` instead (with the same arguments. Though `shell=False` is not needed, since it's the default).

Comment: Your second issue seems to be unrelated to the first one. In that case, it's more suited as a second, independent question.

Comment: @9769953 as it runs as a subprocess I'm not sure why sys.argv[2] didn't work, all I know is that the video file did not get created with the new video name.

My understanding was that I couldn't use subprocess.run() because it would wait for the subprocess to complete before moving on and I need it to continue in the main script so I can record what happens.

I will remove the shell=False argument thanks

Comment: @9769953 When I run sys.argv[2] in the subprocess I get --stdin=9003 as the output. So it seems like stdin is doing something but I'm unsure on how to read this